# Cleanest way to import/require a Vue.js directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to organize my plugins into custom Vue Directives that could be a simple as:

```
Vue.directive('popout', {
    bind() {
        $(this.el).popOut();
    }
});
```

And save these in separate files, to be imported in either the main JS file or the Vue(ify) components with something like:

```
require('./directives/popout.js');
```

I've tried a number of `export default` setups, but I can't seem to get it to work. What would be the cleanest (i.e. best-practice) way to do this?

Comment: directive is a no-no

Comment: Since you seemt o want to register them globally (`Vue.directive(...)`) there's nothing you want to import from these files, there's no need for any exports. Just make sure you `import Vue from 'vue'` in them.

Comment: Hi Oscar, I'm wondering if you ever found a solution to this and if you could share it  - thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution,below is the code

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const global= {
 bind(el, binding, vnode) {
     console.log('you code');
 }
};
```

this code goes in lets say directive/global.js file.
Then in you app.js or entry point file use this

```
import { global } from './directive/global.js';
Vue.directive('global', global);
```

first line will import the directive as we are using same name to only used global, second line to make you directive global. Hope it help.